# React.ReactNode as argument in storybook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components, storybook, system-design

This is my button component type

```
import React from 'react'
export type ButtonProps = {
  label: string;
  color?:'primary' | 'secondary' | 'tertiary';
  size?:'mobile' | 'tablet' | 'desktop',
  handleClick?:()=>void,
  fullWidth?:boolean,
  loading?:boolean
  href?:string,
  icon?:React.ReactNode
  target?:'_blank' | '_parent'
  disabled?:boolean
}
```

I'm using button component in storybook .

**Storybook Code**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Meta, StoryObj } from "@storybook/react";
import { Button as SampleButton } from "../../components";
import 'antd/dist/reset.css';

const buttonMeta: Meta<typeof SampleButton> = {
  title: "Components/Button",
  tags: ['autodocs'],
  component: SampleButton,
};

export default buttonMeta;

type Story = StoryObj<typeof buttonMeta>;

export const Primary: Story = {
  args: {
    label: "Testing",
    icon: React.createElement('h1', null, 'Icon')
  },
};
```

right now i'm using React.createElement to add element of react for icon in args but if i use simple tag of any html it gave error that can't find name {tag}.

Is there any way to add html tags or react component/element to args of storybook.
in my next component there will be a condition in which i have to add form as a child in args and according to this way (React.createElement) it will be very difficult.

Is there any solution or a way to fix this.

**For refrence**

Storybook Main.ts

```
import type { StorybookConfig } from "@storybook/react-webpack5";
const config: StorybookConfig = {
  // ["../src/stories/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"]
  stories: ["../src/stories/**/*.mdx", "../src/stories/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
    '@storybook/addon-docs'
  ],
  framework: {
    name: "@storybook/react-webpack5",
    options: {
      
    },
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: "tag",
  },
  staticDirs: ["..\\public"],
};
export default config;
```

**Error**
[image: Error]

Answer (score 7):

You can change file name from `Button.stories.ts` to `Button.stories.tsx`